# Subtract two columns of two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

dt1:

```
        date        value
0       20000101    2
1       20100101    5
```

dt2:

```
        date        value
0       20000101    1
1       20100101    1
```

The new data frame is the subtraction of dt1.value and dt2.value:

```
        date        value
0       20000101    1
1       20100101    4
```

How to do that ?

Comment: You need to format your question properly and be more specific and detailed in your question. Once you do that, the community will be able to answer. Else, its uncleae what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting `index` on `index` and `date` columns and subtract two `dataframe`:

```
dt = (dt1.set_index(['index', 'date'])- dt2.set_index(['index', 'date'])).reset_index()
dt
```

Result:

```
   index      date  value
0      0  20000101      1
1      1  20100101      4
```

Or, you can copy `dt1` to new dataframe and update the `value` column by result of subtraction:

```
dt = dt1.copy()
dt['value'] = dt1['value'] - dt2['value']
```

Looking at `timeit`, the `copy` and updating value seems much faster than indexing, subtracting, and resetting index:

```
%%timeit
dt = (dt1.set_index(['index', 'date'])- dt2.set_index(['index', 'date'])).reset_index()
dt
```

Result:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 4.35 ms per loop
```

For `copy`:

```
%%timeit
dt = dt1.copy()
dt['value'] = dt1['value'] - dt2['value']
```

Result:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 371 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sub`

```
dt1.set_index(["index", "date"]).sub(dt2.set_index(["index", "date"]), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: 20000101, 1: 20100101}, 'value': {0: 2, 1: 5}})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: 20000101, 1: 20100101}, 'value': {0: 1, 1: 1}})
```

You can use sbtract:

```
df1.assign(value=df1.value-df2.value)
Out[253]: 
       date  value
0  20000101      1
1  20100101      4
```

Comment: nope, not working by simply sub the whole dataframes.

Comment: It works with your sample data. What's not working with your actual data?

Comment: The date column value is all zero.

Comment: can you update the example data so that it can reproduce your error?

Comment: Remove the "index"

Comment: No worries. Please upvote and accept answer if you find it helpful.